# Create one big array from object properties using Undescore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following structure:

```
Object = {
1:[..],
2:[..],
3:[..],
4:[..]
}
```

Where each property is just a array of strings.

I would like to know, how can I create one big array of all unique elements, using just underscore.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use pure JS solutions?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, since I am already using Underscore in my project, why not use it fully..

Comment: are the elements into the arrays unique? if no, what's the policy for choosing one instead of another?

Comment: underscore.js built by using js. And they would have written it in a generic way by checking some conditions. I am not telling you to not to use it. But try to use pure js where ever it is possible. A pure js solution would be, https://jsfiddle.net/su7a5hmb/

Comment: `since I am already using Underscore in my project, why not use it fully` - because native functions are often faster than library ones, and depending on what "big" is, you may need the native speed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this object:

```
var o = {
    1:['3','4'],
    2:['5','6'],
    3:['7','8'],
    4:['9','10']
}
```

You can flatten all the object's values:

```
var arr = _.flatten(_.values(o));
// [ '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10' ]
```

Getting the array.

EDIT:
I used numbers, where the question is about strings. It holds for any kind of data.

To remove duplicates, you can use [_.uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) which works for strings and numbers out of the box.

Comment: Nice answer. This would be a good place to use underscore's chain function so it would look something like: `_.chain(o).values().flatten().uniq().value();`